# Remove double space in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, whitespace, replace

I need to remove the any double space (two spaces) that comes anywhere in the text in one my database tables..

I tried:

```
update items set description= replace(description, '  ', ' ')
```

but this removes if it is only the spaces..  but the "description" cells has many words like: "any text here  more", so I need to remove the two spaces before the word "more" at the example before, and leave everything else as is..  just replace the double space with one space anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use trim command, please refer this

http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamespipe/archive/2007/08/14/SQL_3A00_-A-49-character-long-_2700_empty_2700_-field_3F00_.aspx

or try this

```
update items set description= replace(description,space(2),space(1))
```

Comment: It says it "removes both leading and trailing white spaces", not double spaces in between words

Answer (score 0):

try this if work for you ,

```
update items set description= replace(description, 'SPACE(2)', ' ')
```

but
this is working well i tested,

```
update items set description= replace(description, '   ', ' ') WHERE id=1
```

Comment: it gave me: "0 rows affected"